# ''min $c^tx$ subject to $x^tAx=1$'': is is possible to solve it with Lagrange multiplier or in the scope of KKT?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

I find a problem:

> Minimize $c^tx$ subject to $x^tAx=1$, where $A$ is a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix.

But the question obligates to use KKT but I am trying to apply simple Lagrange multiplier solution but cannot cope with it.

Is that question solvable via Lagrange Multiplier or this method is only available for linear equality constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a positive **definite** matrix then you can use usual Lagrangian methods but if $A$ is only positive *semi*-definite matrix then you have some constraint on the $x_s$ that is missing from your original question. For example, if $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ and $c=(-1,2)$ then there is no bounded solution. The "solution" in this example is $x_1=-\infty$ and $x_2=1$.

In what follows *I assume $A$ is a positive definite matrix*.

The first-order condition for the optimization problem give us:

$$c - \lambda\,\left(A^t+A\right)x=0 \Rightarrow x=\dfrac{\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}{\lambda}\Rightarrow x^tAx=\dfrac{c^t \left(\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}\right)^tA\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}{\lambda^2}=\dfrac{c^t \left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}A\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}{\lambda^2}=1$$ 
where $\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix of $\left(A^t+A\right)$ (notice that the existence of $\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}$ is not guaranteed if $A$ were to be only *semi* definite). So $\lambda=\sqrt{c^t \left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}A\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}$ and we finally get: $$ \boxed{x=\dfrac{\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}{\sqrt{c^t \left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}A\left(A^t+A\right)^{-1}c}}}.$$

Suggestion: don't get intimidated with vector calculus. It always helps to do simpler versions of the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to check you are on the right track.

Side work: $\nabla_x\left( c^t x\right) = c$ so $\nabla_x\left( y^tAx\right)= A^t y$ and $\nabla_y\left( y^tAx\right)= Ax$.

Comment: what if equality constraint become inequality constraint

Comment: If there is a bounded solution, it should be easy to show that even if you have inequality at the optimal the constraint will bind. The more delicate question is if whether there is a solution in this case but if A is positive definite the constraint set should be compact so I guess you also always have a solution. I'm at a bar drinking beer so maybe wrong... Cheers!